# C# .net 7 vs .net core 3.1: EF core produces different queries for mySQL

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework-core

Essentially I am trying to produce the following SQL query via Linq:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `CustomerMainTable` AS `t`
WHERE `t`.`CustomerMainTableId` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`t0`.`CustomerMainTableId`)
    FROM `CustomerMainTable` AS `t0`
    GROUP BY `t0`.`CustomerMainTableCustomerId`
)
```

`CustomerMainTableId` is an autoincrement id, and `CustomerMainTableCustomerId` is the customer's unique ID.
There can be multiple entries of the customer's transaction in the `CustomerMainTableId`, so the idea is to select the latest transaction for each customer by grouping and selecting the max id.

In entity framework core 3.1, this was achieved via:

```cs
var CustomerGroupQuery = _DB.CustomerMainTable.Where(p => _DB.CustomerMainTable
    .GroupBy(l => l.CustomerMainTableCustomerId)
    .Select(g => g.Max(c => c.CustomerMainTableId))
    .Contains(p.CustomerMainTableId));
```

However, the same query, when executed in EF Core 6 or 7 produces a wrong query in SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `CustomerMainTable` AS `t`
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM `CustomerMainTable` AS `t0`
    GROUP BY `t0`.`CustomerMainTableCustomerId`
    HAVING MAX(`t0`.`CustomerMainTableId`) = `t`.`CustomerMainTableId`)
```

Interestingly enough, if we split the Linq query like so:

```cs
List<int> idlist = _DB.CustomerMainTable
    .GroupBy(l => l.CustomerMainTableCustomerId)
    .Select(g => g.Max(c => c.CustomerMainTableId)).ToList();

var CustomerGroupQuery = _DB.CustomerMainTable.Where(p => idlist.Contains(p.CustomerMainTableId));
```

It produces the correct query - but requires a list of integers to be returned.. which is less than ideal.

Might anyone know of a workaround for this issue?

Comment: The original query (both SQL and LINQ) were wrong to begin with. LINQ over an ORM isn't a replacement for SQL. ORMs deal with application *entities*, not database tables, trying to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of database tables. There's no `CustomerMainTable` in an application, there are `Customer` entities

Comment: As for the query itself, what is it trying to do? How come there are both `CustomerMainTableCustomerId` and `CustomerMainTableId` columns in the same table? Why would there *ever* be duplicate `CustomerMainTableId` for the same `CustomerMainTableCustomerId` ? That's a database design problem *and* an ORM mapping problem. An ORM *Maps Objects* to Relational tables, and works well when you can map 1 object to 1 row. If you have to write such a complex query to just get the ID, there's a DB design problem. Either fix it or map to a *view* that returns single rows

Comment: Are you trying to do "soft deletes" or maintain history in the `Customers` table? SQL Server has temporal tables that solve this. The standard way to handle this in SQL, the language, is to use a separate table for current and historical data (Customers and CustomersHistory). Simply for performance reasons you *don't* want to have to group just to get a single object.

Comment: If you have to maintain history in the *same* table, it's far faster and easier to keep `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` columns that are maintained automatically through eg triggers. This way, to get the current row you only need to filter by `Id=@id and GETDATE() BETWEEN ValidFrom and ValidTo`. If the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` columns are indexed, you only need a simple index seek to find the current row

Comment: PS: The new SQL isn't wrong either and probably *better* than the original. You're looking for the rows whose `CustomerMainTableId` is equal to the `MAX(CustomerMainTableId)` per `CustomerMainTableCustomerId`. That's exactly what the new SQL query does too, but takes advantage of the indexes covering the `CustomerMainTableCustomerId` column. The original query would have to calculate the `MAX` values for the *entire* table, cache them to memory or spool them to TempDB and only then filter the table by their value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF Core 6 and 7 you can use other technique how to get latest record of the group:

```cs
var CustomerGroupQuery = _DB.CustomerMainTable
     .GroupBy(l => l.CustomerMainTableCustomerId)
     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.CustomerMainTableId).First());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Might you know why the old query (using the select max statement) stopped working in entity 7?

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone else - EFCore confirms they will roll back the "exists" statement back to a "where in":
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30955

It looks like the change impacts other databases significantly more than MS-SQL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).